# Android Room get field from other table

Tags: android, sql, foreign-keys, android-room

In my application I have two tables: Operations and Categories.

**Operation table**

```
@Entity(tableName = "OperationsTable")
public class Operation
{
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    private int OperationNumber;
    private int Year;
    private int Month;
    private int Day;
    private String Category;
    private float Amount;
}
```

**Categories table**

```
public class Category implements Serializable
{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "CategoryName")
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "CategoryType")
    private String type;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "IconID")
    private int iconID;
}
```

Until now I was making a query that returned a subset of Operation:

```
@Query("SELECT Category as CategoryName, SUM(Amount) as OperationQuantity FROM OperationsTable WHERE Year = :year AND KindOfOperation = 'Gasto' AND Month = :month GROUP BY Category ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC")
LiveData<List<OperationSubset>> getCategorizedExpensesInMonth(Integer year, Integer month);
```

The subset is this:

```
public class OperationSubset
{
    @ColumnInfo(name = "CategoryName")
    public String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "OperationQuantity")
    public float quantity;
}
```

Now I'd like to return the same subset but adding a field from Categories table:

```
public class OperationSubsetDesired
{
    @ColumnInfo(name = "CategoryName")
    public String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "OperationQuantity")
    public float quantity;

    public float iconID <-- from Categories table
}
```

I know I must use relations but I'm struggling with this.

Comment: These entities are un diferent tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Query("SELECT Category as CategoryName, SUM(Amount) as OperationQuantity, Categories.IconID" +
            " FROM OperationsTable LEFT JOIN Categories ON OperationsTable.Category = Categories.CategoryName" +
            " WHERE Year = :year AND KindOfOperation = 'Gasto' AND Month = :month GROUP BY Category ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC")
```

It should be like this. If you will use relation annotation your object structure will be different.
More info about joins you can check here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp